# Why does BeautifulSoup not find all tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I use BeautifulSoup 4 to parse http://www.madcamcnc.com/sales.html, and then look for table tags, it finds 2.  When I look at the page's html, I see 10 tables.  Why doesn't BeautifulSoup return all 10?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.madcamcnc.com/sales.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print len(soup.findAll('table'))
```

Comment: How many does it return?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about looking at the wrong web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing the source shows there are only 3 tables in the actual HTML source code for the page. Other tables must be added later using Javascript after the page load, which BeautifulSoup doesn't see.

BeautifulSoup can only work on the given HTML document, but does not load or execute Javascript hence the differences between the browser and the document BeautifulSoup processes.

[image]

Comment: how do you get 3 and I got 2? I copy/pasted the source and searched for the word `table` - four matches, two each of `<table>` and `</table>`...

Comment: @MattDMo Beats me... I've added in a screenshot of the source I see.

Comment: aha. You're looking at one of the `<iframe>`'s - sales_region.html.

Comment: I wonder if the OP somehow got all of the iframe sources mixed in with the main page...

Comment: Mixing in the iframes is also possible, but my main problem is that I was looking at the page after the Javascript changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two sets of `<table>...</table>` tags in that page's source...

There are plenty more `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, but only two tables.